# Laravel 5.6 custom rule validation

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a function for validation rule in add/edit "localities"

I have checked the name field as unique in "localities" table.

I have one more field "is_deleted" in localities table. If the "is_deleted" field value is 1, then it didn't ask the validation (i.e) No need to ask "Name is already in use".

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'unique:localities'],
            'city_id' => ['required']
        ];
    }
```

How to create a custom rule for this condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude/ignore by adding column name and id,like

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'unique:localities,name,1,is_deleted'],
        'city_id' => ['required']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi @C2486, The code is working. Thanks. But in the edit localities how can i change this  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('localities')->ignore(request()->segment(3))],
            'city_id' => ['required']
        ];
    }

Comment: @KamesP : It seem like different from current question, Please add it as new question.

Comment: In case of edit you need to ignore id for localities also `'unique:localities,name,'.$id.',id,1,is_deleted'` where `$id` will be current id of localities